# RestKit - POST response object mapping

Tags: objective-c, ios, json, restkit

I have method "getBuses" on my RESTful webservice (Rails). That method needs to return 
me list of buses in JSON. But, when I sending request for "/getBuses.json" I 
need to send

```
params = [NSDictionary 
dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: @"2011-08-16", @"datum", @"TRUE", 
@"fromSerbia", nil];
```

I'm posting params because I need filtered response (just for specific 
tour on specific date). 
Then, I expecting response like this:

```
{ 
  "buses" : [ { 
    "bus_number" : "1", 
    "created_at" : "2011-08-15T23:07:52Z", 
    "id" : 1, 
    "lat" : 44.815, 
    "long" : 20.4665, 
    "model" : "Setra", 
    "registar_number" : "123456", 
    "seats" : 50, 
    "tour_id" : 1, 
    "updated_at" : "2011-08-15T23:07:52Z" 
  }, { 
    "bus_number" : "2", 
    "created_at" : "2011-08-15T23:07:52Z", 
    "id" : 2, 
    "lat" : 44.812, 
    "long" : 20.465, 
    "model" : "Mercedes", 
    "registar_number" : "2234", 
    "seats" : 60, 
    "tour_id" : 1, 
    "updated_at" : "2011-08-15T23:07:52Z" 
  } ] 
}
```

I just need NSArray with Bus objects. 
**Can you give me code example how to make this request and make object mapping with RestKit?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I told you in the IRC Channel, in your RKClient instance you can use this method:

(NSURL *)URLForResourcePath:(NSString *)resourcePath queryParams:(NSDictionary *)queryParams

So you should do it like this:

```
[objectManager.mappingProvider setMapping:busesMapping forKeyPath:@"buses"];

params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: @"2011-08-16", @"datum", @"TRUE", @"fromSerbia", nil];
NSURL *someURL = [objectManager.client URLForResourcePath:@"/service/getLocations.json" queryParams:params];

[objectManager loadObjectsAtResourcePath:[someURL absoluteString] delegate:self];
```

That method builds a valid URL using the resourcePath and the parameters you give as parameter. And then you need to set it back using the absoluteString of the NSURL object. Hope this helps!